# MAC - Docker commands hanging

Tags: macos, docker

all of my docker commands are hanging, for example when i run

`docker image ls`

Docker version : 17.12.0
Mac Version: 10.13.3

Comment: I will try to install the latest version of docker

Comment: Also try clearing all what you have https://davidwalsh.name/docker-remove-all-images-containers

Answer (score 10):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1835) for Docker on Mac. I faced the same issue when I tried to dig a little deeper into this problem, and found a solution that worked for me.

By default, Docker allocates 4 CPU cores to the `docker` daemon. When your docker hangs, if you check the CPU utilization on your machine via the Activity Monitor, you will probably see that the process takes 400% of the CPU - which means that it's maxing out on CPU and thus becomes unresponsive.

While the eventual fix would have to be provided by the Docker team, what you can do is allocate more cores to your Docker process so that it doesn't keep hanging. You can do that by clicking on the `Docker` icon at the top right on your Mac. Then navigate to `Preferences -> Advanced`. There, you can increase the number of CPU cores you want to allocate to Docker. Changing it from 4 to 6 did the trick for me. You can even try to increase the max-memory you want to allocate to the process, though I don't suspect memory is the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have added CPUS to 4,  Memory to 2.5GB, Swap to 1.0GB. Now it works well on my MacPro 2017.

Comment: For anyone experiencing the same, my CPU wasn't maxing out for Docker in Activity Monitor but upping the CPU helped anyway

Comment: Didn't work for me, but the option is now under Settings-> Resources.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation.

I am using Docker Desktop 18.x.

1. Try disabling Kubernetes (*Preferences* ➞ *Kubernetes* menu option) and see if the response arrives quickly. Docker will try to update Kubernetes and this can take some time.
2. Maybe you already have  Docker installed through Homebrew. 
   This command may help: `brew uninstall --force docker`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to solve this was to choose "Reset to factory defaults" from the Troubleshoot menu (or the bug icon if you have that).

I previously tried reinstalling, increasing the CPU and swap allocation, clean/purge, and moving the files in `.docker`. I was hoping for a less invasive option.